# How can you fairly split CPU between multiple JVMs running on a single SmartOS server?

Tags: java, solaris, opensolaris, smartos, joyent

I currently run an app within Tomcat but want to deploy Play Framework on the same servers as well. For licensing reasons, this is cost efficient, but being able to use excess CPU usage on a beefier instance should be beneficial as well.

If I'm running Tomcat and Play on the same (Joyent / SmartOS) server, is there a way to ensure that one app doesn't hog all the CPU?

Will that just happen naturally if I want a 50/50 split? What if I want one app to have a minimum of 75% available and the other to have 25% minimum?

It seems possible to do this with CPU shares for separate zones, but I wasn't sure if this was possible for different processes within a SmartOS zone or if there were other facilities to handle this.

Comment: when you say smartos zone are you referring to the global zone?

Comment: I'm referring to the zone that I'm provisioned by Joyent as a "smart machine" (a share limited slice of the physical machine for which I'm paying),  which I believe is not the global zone.